# OBS Studio + NVidia GeForce: is it possible to record in higher resolution than the display permits?

Tags: graphics-card, resolution, opensuse, nvidia-geforce, obs-studio

The relevant part of my setup:

- A monitor with a maximum resolution 1920x1200
- NVIDIA GeForce 2070 Super
- OpenSuse Leap 15.2
- OBS Studio installed and working

I've either read or heard somewhere, that with NVIDIA graphics cards it is possible, with some tweaks, to record the screen with a higher resolution than the maximum resolution of the physical monitor. Does anyone know, if it possible at all, how to do it on OpenSuse?

**Edit:**

It seems my question boils down to "Does NVIDIA Control Panel for Linux exist?". All that I've got is `nvidia-settings` utility, but I do not see any options Windows users are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, this is possible as follows if the NVIDIA Control Panel is
installed and the procedure below is supported by your display adapter.

- Right-click the desktop and run the NVIDIA Control Panel
- Position to *3D Settings > Manage 3D settings > Global Settings*
- Set DSR Factors to "4.00x (native resolution)" (or less)
- Click Apply
- Log out and back into Windows
- Right click again the desktop and choose "Display settings"
  – Click ‘Advanced Display Settings’
- You should now have available the Display resolution of
  3840 x 2160 that wasn’t there before.
- Record the screen using
  [NVIDIA ShadowPlay](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/geforce-experience/shadowplay/)
  or
  [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/).

Useful references:

- [How to record 4K screen capture on a HD monitor](https://stormystudio.com/record-4k-hd-monitor/)
- [How to enable Dynamic Super Resolution in games](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3587/%7E/how-to-enable-dynamic-super-resolution-in-games.)

---

For Linux, this depends on the driver, but try the following:

- Enter this command line:

  ```
    xrandr
  ```

  Choose the output that is connected, say `DP-1.
- Run the following command:

  ```
    xrandr --output DP-1 --scale 2x2
  ```

  The monitor may go black for a second, then should come back again at
  double resolution.
- To switch the screen back to normal you use:

  ```
   xrandr --output DP-1 --scale 1x1
  ```

Comment: My question is how to do it on OpenSuse Linux.

Comment: Added the commands for Linux (if they work for you).